# how are android contacts listed?

Tags: android

Sorry for the basic question, and if there is a better sub-forum pls let me know. Here is my question: when downloading or extracting a phonebook/contact list from an android phone - how are contacts organized? My contact list in question has each contact assigned a number (1- ~400) but the contacts are not listed in any logical order. Are they always listed by date of entry into the contact list? Or something else? If I was to guess, I would have expected they would have been listed alphabetically by contact name (last or first) however that was not the case. They are somewhat alphabetically listed, but not completely. The Phone in question is an android powered Kyocera M6000 Zio.

Answer (score 1):

It’s a relational database. If you don’t ask for any specific order, the order is unspecified.